# iOS Tab Bar Image Size Increasing On Tap

Tags: ios, objective-c, svg, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a tab bar on iOS and I set the tab bar images using SVGs. The SVGs are set via the [XamSvg plugin](https://components.xamarin.com/view/xamsvg).

I want the central tabbar item image to be larger than the ones on the other tabs. To do so, I use this code in

In AwakeFromNib:

```
CenterTab.Image = SvgFactory.FromBundle(ViewModel.Images.CenterTabSvg, 24);
CenterTab.ImageInsets = new UIEdgeInsets(-5, -5, -5, -5);
```

It works but every time I tap on the center tab, its image size keeps increasing. [image]

I also tried this with no success:

```
var centerImage = SvgFactory.FromBundle(ViewModel.Images.CenterTab, 40).ImageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal);
            CenterTab.SetFinishedImages(centerImage,centerImage);
            centerImage.ImageInsets = new UIEdgeInsets(3,-13,-5,-5);
```

Comment: Try to resize tabbar item image.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
UITabBarItem *centerTab = [self.tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2];

[centerTab setImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"iconGray.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];//Your Image
[centerTab setSelectedImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"iconBlue.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];//Your Image
```